# Google Translate: tracking the foreign language in web page

Tags: google, web-development, google-translate

How do I track where the language is coming from? If I'm building a website, and I end up putting together plugins, I'd like to know where the foreign language is coming from?

When I'm testing my page, I'm getting Google Translate.

Answer (score 1):

You can track the usage of [Google Translate for websites](https://translate.google.com/manager/website/) by using Google Analytics which is very common for webmasters for tracking all types of usesful things.

Once you've setup [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) head over to Event Tracking > Actions and there should be a row with translation actions.